# Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin without solution

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, cors, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to fix the following problem since more than 10 days. I red all the guides and pages from this site without solution.
I developed a REST Web Server using Jersey library in java. The result of the service is in JSON format. In my server I add the CORS filter

**SERVER**

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

   @Override
   public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                      final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
   }

}
```

and the web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>conferenceServer</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-    class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>server</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-    name>javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter</param-name>
            <param-value>server.CORSFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The JSON formatter of the response is valid but when I call the service in my app, I receive this message error:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (all, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://****/myServer/service. Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

In your opinion, where is the problem?

Comment: Your XML isnt valid `<param-     name>` -> `<param-name>`

Comment: it's a copy-paste error. it isn't in my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this works as a param-name

```
<param-name>javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter</param-name>
```

Two things you can do to make sure the filter is registered:

1. Add `@Provider` on top of the filter class. The init-param

   ```
   jersey.config.server.provider.packages
   ```

   will make sure that it's picked up from the package scan and registered.
2. Use the init-param `...classnames` to register the filter

   ```
   <init-param>
       <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
       <param-value>server.CORSFilter</param-value>
   </init-param>
   ```

Comment: I just made your corrections but the error is not corrected. How can I make sure that it is a mistake SERVER side (and thus a problem CORS filter set wrong) and not CLIENT side?

Comment: is the filter being called?

Comment: how should I check?

Comment: You can just add a simple log statement in the filter

Comment: The filter is called (I put a System.out in the function)! When I use the link of the service in a browser, the result is correct (I receive the JSON vector). If I call the the service in my Cordova app I receive the error. Can I post the link? I uploaded my server application on a external server

Comment: Might be a problem with cordova. I've used it a while ago, but not too familiar with it. From what I remember I had to do something that involved whitelisting. I cant remember exactly what it was. You might want to look into it. It might just be a problem with cordova, and not your server.

Comment: Check [this out](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/)

Comment: No. On the client, in the http call, I deleted the headers: "access-control-allow-origin" : "*"